# How to reduce committed heap memory in JVM

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, jvm

Our JVMs are consuming more memory than expected. We did some profiling and found that there is no leak. Used heap memory goes till 2.9 GB max but it comes down to 800 MB during idle time. But committed heap increased till 3.5 GB (sometimes 4 GB) and never comes down. Also after the idle time, when used heap increases from 800 MB, then committed heap memory gets increased from 3.5 GB. So our server reaches max memory size soon and we have to restart them every other day.

My questions are

1. My understanding is that committed heap memory is currently allocated memory. When used heap memory reduces why is the committed memory not getting reduced as well?
2. When used heap memory increases from its level (800 MB) committed heap memory also get increased from its level (from 3.5GB)

We have the below memory settings in our servers:

```
-Xmx4096M -Xms1536M -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: Committed means allocated by the jvm; your max heap size is 4gigs, so that, when needed, the committed memory goes up to that threashold. Then it _might_ be given back to the system, but probably in your case the jvm does not feel the need to do that.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryUsage.html

Comment: I would only give the JVM the amount of memory you have available e.g. 3 GB perhaps and then you shouldn't need to restart it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to tune -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio which is "maximum percentage of heap free after GC to avoid shrinking". Default value = 70

Comment: I have added this, but Heap size is not shrinking after GC. I gave XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio as 10 for testing purpose but actual free space is more than that. Some forums I read that JVM will never release the memory once it acquired. Is that true or do I need add any other parameter to control it.

Comment: Its working now when I add -XX:+UseSerialGC, Is it any other issues I need to face if I give this option ?

Comment: OK, understand. Will it impact CPU utilization as well ? Without using it Heap size is not shrinking. Do we have any other alternative way

Comment: Try UseG1GC it is both fast and can shrink (it seems)

Comment: It works only when I do click "Perform GC" in jvisualvm. But when system does gc, it doesn't reduce the heap size, it just reduce used heap. We can't manually do "perform gc" every day

Comment: I think shrink may happen only when GC runs. You may create a timer which will test memory (free / committed) and run System.gc() when needed

Comment: Actually, you can simply run System.gc perodically, memory properties do not change until we run gc